# Finding the constant $a$ such that $af^n$ is a pdf given that $f$ is a normal pdf

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I need to find the value of the constant $a$ such that $af^n$ is a pdf given that $f$ is a normal pdf with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

---

My attempt: I tried to look at the integral of the normal pdf over the real line, multiply it by $a$, and set it equal to $1$. But I didn't know what to do with the $n$ in the exponent.

Comment: could you define af^n  ?

Comment: All I know is that f is normal

Comment: i mean the syntax "af^n". you want to know the density function of $g=af^n$, where a is constant ?

Comment: Correct. af^n is essentially a new density

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf of the variable $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ can be expressed in terms of the standard normal pdf $\phi(x)$ as follows:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$
So we have

$$af_X(x)^n=\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^n=\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\phi\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}x-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)^n$$ 
in order to be pdf, you should have $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}af_X(x)^ndx=1$$
You can use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) to find the integral and solve the above equation for $a$.

Comment: On that link I only see the proper form as an indefinite integral. How do you do the infinite limits for the standard normal cdf?

Comment: You should know that $\Phi(-\infty)=0$ and $\Phi(+\infty)=1$.

Comment: I see. Also I noticed that in your initial definition of f(x) that the term in the parentheses is Z. What would be the expected value of E[Z*$\rm {\Phi}$(Z)]?